# How to create a vline or column line for my table?

Tags: tables

I want to create a vline or column line for my table, it can only created the vline for the head and the first column, but not for the rest of the columns' body.

[image]

Here is my code:

```
\begin{table}[h]
            \begin{center}
                \begin{tabular}{c | c | c | c | c }
                    \hline
                    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{$p$} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{$q$} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{$p \land q$}  & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{$p \lor q$}  & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{$p \oplus q$} \\
                    \hline
                    {\multirow{1}{*}
                        {{\parbox[t]{0.4cm}{T }}}}
                    & \multicolumn{1}{c}   
                    {\multirow{1}{*}
                        {{\parbox[t]{0.4cm}{T}}}} 
                    & \multicolumn{1}{c}   
                    {\multirow{1}{*}
                        {{\parbox[t]{0.4cm}{T}}}} 
                    & \multicolumn{1}{c}   
                    {\multirow{1}{*}
                        {{\parbox[t]{0.4cm}{T}}}} 
                    & \multicolumn{1}{c}   
                    {\multirow{1}{*}
                        {{\parbox[t]{0.4cm}{F}}}}
                    
                    \\ 
                    \\
                    {\multirow{1}{*}
                        {{\parbox[t]{0.4cm}{T}}}}   
                    & \multicolumn{1}{c}
                    {\multirow{1}{*}
                        {{\parbox[t]{0.4cm}{F}}}} 
                    & \multicolumn{1}{c}   
                    {\multirow{1}{*}
                        {{\parbox[t]{0.4cm}{F}}}} 
                    & \multicolumn{1}{c}   
                    {\multirow{1}{*}
                        {{\parbox[t]{0.4cm}{T}}}} 
                    & \multicolumn{1}{c}   
                    {\multirow{1}{*}
                        {{\parbox[t]{0.4cm}{T}}}}
                    \\ 
                    \\
                    {\multirow{1}{*}
                        {{\parbox[t]{0.4cm}{F}}}}   
                    & \multicolumn{1}{c}
                    {\multirow{1}{*}
                        {{\parbox[t]{0.4cm}{T}}}} 
                    & \multicolumn{1}{c}   
                    {\multirow{1}{*}
                        {{\parbox[t]{0.4cm}{F}}}} 
                    & \multicolumn{1}{c}   
                    {\multirow{1}{*}
                        {{\parbox[t]{0.4cm}{T}}}} 
                    & \multicolumn{1}{c}   
                    {\multirow{1}{*}
                        {{\parbox[t]{0.4cm}{T}}}}
                    \\ 
                    \\
                    {\multirow{1}{*}
                        {{\parbox[t]{0.4cm}{F}}}}   
                    & \multicolumn{1}{c}
                    {\multirow{1}{*}
                        {{\parbox[t]{0.4cm}{F}}}} 
                    & \multicolumn{1}{c}   
                    {\multirow{1}{*}
                        {{\parbox[t]{0.4cm}{F}}}} 
                    & \multicolumn{1}{c}   
                    {\multirow{1}{*}
                        {{\parbox[t]{0.4cm}{F}}}} 
                    & \multicolumn{1}{c}   
                    {\multirow{1}{*}
                        {{\parbox[t]{0.4cm}{F}}}}
                \end{tabular}
                \caption{The truth table for the Conjunction, Disjunction and Exclusive or}
            \end{center}
        \end{table}
```

Comment: Please write a minimal working example. See [link](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/250119) for more details what it means.

Comment: From the look of it you can probably get the problem resolved by get rid of the multirow and multicolumn commands. Or alternatively specify the inner specification as `|c|` or something.

Comment: remove all the `\multirow` which are doing nothing useful, but are preventing the vertical rule. Also urelated but `[h]`means not top or bottom of page or on a page of tables, so usually givs no legal place the table can be placed, latex will give a warning about that. `[htp]` is usually a better choice.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle thanks for the advice, I was learning latex and a bit clumsy do not really understand h literally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- I'm not sure what you after, but I'm suspect that you may looking for the following:

[image]

```
\documentclass[parsk multirowip=half-]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{makecell}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[h]
    \setcellgapes{3pt}
    \makegapedcells
\centering
    \begin{tabular}{| c | c | c | c | c |}
        \hline
$p$ & $q$   & $p\land q$    & $p\lor q$ & $p \oplus q$  \\  \hline
T   & T     & T             & T         & F             \\
T   & F     & F             & T         & T             \\
F   & T     & F             & T         & T             \\
F   & F     & F             & F         & F 
    \end{tabular}
\caption{The truth table for the Conjunction, Disjunction and Exclusive or}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

- As already mentioned in comments below your question, most of your code doing nothing, i.e. are just a clutter. I remove them.

**Edit:**
A bit more simple and shorter code for your table is by using `tabularray` package for the writing your table:

```
\documentclass[parsk multirowip=half-]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[h]
\centering
    \begin{tblr}{hline{1,2,Z}, vlines,
                 colspec = {*{5}{Q[c, wd=2em]}},
                 rowsep  = 3pt,
                 row{1}  = {mode=math}
                 }
p   & q & p\land q  & p\lor q   & p\oplus q \\
T   & T & T         & T         & F         \\
T   & F & F         & T         & T         \\
F   & T & F         & T         & T         \\
F   & F & F         & F         & F         \\
    \end{tblr}
\caption{The truth table for the Conjunction, Disjunction and Exclusive or}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: yes +1 , although your `tabularray` assimilation is so complete,  you load the package even when using a classic tabular:-) (oh, it went:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, in the first I intent to use `tabularray`, but then I change the mind and use `tabular` and forgot it to delete. Now is already deleted.

Comment: and now it's back:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, :-) :-). Yes, as new example ....

Answer (score 0):

The bar `|` between two columns in column spec. adds a vertical line to a table

[image]

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{*2{wc{0.45cm}} | *3{wc{0.75cm}}}
        \hline
        \(p\) & \(q\) & \(p\land q\) & \(p\lor q\) & \(p \oplus q\) \\
        \hline
        T & T & T & T & F \\
        T & F & F & T & T \\
        F & T & F & T & T \\
        F & F & F & F & F \\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{The truth table for the Conjunction, Disjunction and Exclusive or}
    \label{tab:table1}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

For instance, changing this line

```
\begin{tabular}{*2{wc{0.45cm}} | *3{wc{0.75cm}}}
```

to

```
\begin{tabular}{| *5{wc{0.75cm}|}}
```

adds vertical lines everywhere. This expression `*5{wc{0.75cm}|}` from `array` shortens the definition of a number of the same columns.

---

Just in case you opt for a better presentation, [booktabs](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=ctan+booktabs&t=canonical&ia=web) is a recommended package with its extra rules and spacing. However, it doesn't work well with vertical lines leaving small gaps. A rememdy is to use `\specialrule` in order to remove extra spacing from rules and add it back using struts. See the solution below. The macros would not be necessary but helps to make the main code for the table tidier

[image]

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}   % for rule alternatives,
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[tbh]
    %%% Local definitions to reduce clutters
    %     can also be in the preamble for global scope
    \newcommand{\ustrut}{\rule{0pt}{11pt}}
    \newcommand{\lstrut}{\rule[-7pt]{0pt}{7pt}}
    \NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\hzrule}{}{%   requires booktabs
        \specialrule{\heavyrulewidth}{0pt}{0pt}}
    \NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\lzrule}{}{%   requires booktabs
        \specialrule{\lightrulewidth}{0pt}{0pt}}
    %%% END of Local Definitions
    \centering
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.1}
    \begin{tabular}{
            *2{wc{0.45cm}}         % column spec.
            | @{\hspace{0.85em}}   % v. bar + extra spacing between 2 columns
            *3{wc{0.75cm}}         % column spec.
        }
        \hzrule
        \(p\) & \(q\) & \(p\land q\) & \(p\lor q\) & \(p \oplus q\) \lstrut \\
        \lzrule
        T & T & T & T & F \ustrut \\
        T & F & F & T & T \\
        F & T & F & T & T \\
        F & F & F & F & F \\
        \hzrule
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{The truth table for the Conjunction, Disjunction and Exclusive or}
    \label{tab:table2}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```